# Excluding reverse matches in SQL

Tags: sql

I’m trying to identify duplicates in a SQL table and my query works great, but I’m struggling with how to exclude reverse matches.  Below is a simple example result table which shows a match and then the reverse match. Any ideas how to only capture the first match that comes up and not include the reversed match?

Match example

- 999: Geoff = 001: Geoff
- 001: Geoff = 999: Geoff

Matching query

```
select ae.id, ae_match.ID matched_ID
from account_email ae
join account_email ae_match on ae.email=ae_match.email and ae.ID!=ae_match.ID
```

Comment: Add some more rows of sample data, and also specify the expected result. I.e. a [mcve]. Also add a tag for the dbms you're using.

Comment: Use `<` instead of `!=`

Comment: What if there's no reverse match for a row, e.g. only the 1st row exists`999: Geoff = 001: Geoff`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by using `<` instead of `!=`:

```sql
select ae.id, ae_match.ID matched_ID
  from account_email ae
  join account_email ae_match
    on (ae.email=ae_match.email
        and ae.ID<ae_match.ID)
```